# how to write a GET requests comparison algorithm?

Tags: javascript, http, web, https, get

In many cases in my day-to-day, I need to compare two [or more] HTTP get requests in order to understand why one's work and the other not or why I'm getting different responses. It's usually large requests with a lot of query params.
I found many tools like this one http-get-requests-compare.com
but I prefer to write my own snippet and then console.table the results in my Devtool.

I know that the order of the query params has no meaning, I tried to compare two requests using JS but I couldn't figure out how to write the algorithm.

my starting point:

```
const requestA = r1.split('&');
const requestB = r2.split('&);
```

Comment: I've meant: "how to write a GET requests comparison simple algorithm"

Comment: can you please share what you've written  ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: We will need a bit more context here. We have no clue what you're talking about, trying to do, or struggle with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many options to write it down.

First, if you want to be a successful engineer I recommend you to improve your algorithm-skills, you can practice in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/), it's one of my favorites.

As for the compare algorithm, first you should remove the prefix [i.e protocol, sub domain, domain name, port etc . . ] and then split and compare each query param to his sibling on the other request, in general it's o[n*m].

I got into the link you addedd [http-get-requests-compare](http://http-get-requests-compare.com) and it seems that all the logic is in the client side you can just learn from them, but trust me, you should practice a bit and write it on your own, it's pretty simple and straightforward algorithm.